# How do I reset Bluetooth-adapter on linux without unplugging USB / rebooting?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

How do I reset Bluetooth-adapter on RaspberryPi v4?
Reset will reset most, but not all settings.
Example the name is not changed.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/ $ sudo hciconfig hci0 name
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: DC:A6:32:02:12:1B  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        Name: 'raspberrypi'
pi@raspberrypi:~/ $ sudo hciconfig hci0 name rpi
pi@raspberrypi:~/ $ sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
pi@raspberrypi:~/$ sudo hciconfig hci0 name
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: UART
        BD Address: DC:A6:32:02:12:1B  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
        Name: 'rpi'
```

Expected the name to change back from 'rpi' to 'raspberrypi'

Answer (score -1):

You also have to reset the service in combination with the adapter:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 reset
sudo invoke-rc.d bluetooth restart
```